# Material keeps applying to other objects instead of just one

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, faces, color

Im trying to make a crab, every time i try to color the lower half it colors the whole body too. The parts are seperated.
[image]

Blender file : https://www.mediafire.com/file/jz5c1o8bctvw1yq/crab.blend/file

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have duplicate objects?

Comment: what do you mean duplicate objects? @JohnEason

Comment: file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/jz5c1o8bctvw1yq/crab.blend/file

Comment: Difficult to tell from your image, but if you select the yellow object (with the claws), does the outline include the underside that you want to colour differently? If so, the yellow might be masking the section you want to change. Now looking at your blend file..

Comment: Ive added it now

Comment: You have two materials in the material slot for your bottom object. The top one is the same as the one for the upper part. Select it and press the - button and the lower colour will then be the default for that object. I suspect you'd already applied a material before you seperated the object so the lower one took the colour of the upper by default.

Comment: thank you that fixed this

Comment: Good. Unless you really need two objects there you could have left it as one object and just applied your new colour to the lower part by selecting the faces and clicking Apply with the second colour selected.